# how to use sp and dp for android web application

Tags: android

I am new to android development. Initially I was using px for font size but later after some research I come to know that I need to use sp and dp which are density independent pixels.

I have just replaced px with dp in my CSS but I am not getting expected output.It is not at all affecting the page. I googled how to use dp and sp but I am not getting any proper example.

Can someone please let me know is replacing px with sp is enough or something else need to be done? Should I also made some changes in my app too or server side CSS changes are enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dp and sp are not CSS properties, they are for native Android controls.  You should consider using

```
font-size: medium;
font-size: small;
```

etc.

for some level of device independence on your WebView's.

You'll also have better success using points (e.g. "pt") vs. pixels.

Also make sure you're aware of meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and its associated properties for scaling.